# Narrowing the criteria of a Ruby 'where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to work out how to narrow a criteria of a where. This is Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3

In this specific case, the following works just fine

```
if params[:show_processed] == "true"
  @logs = @employee.time_logs.all
else
  @logs = @employee.time_logs.non_processed
end
```

However, I then need to apply another criteria into the equation, to further narrow the selection. This is what I tried...

```
if params[:overtime] == 'true'
  @logs = @logs.where(:overtime => true)
end
```

I was assuming I could simply continue to apply criteria to narrow the selection if necessary. However, this is clearly erroneous as Ruby or Rails does not seem to like the where method applied to an array as it returns

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007fc491862678>
```

I have another criteria to apply after this so really need to find a path through it. I was planning on writing it simply like this and then refactoring it. I know that's probably not the most appropriate way but I am relatively new to programming and this seemed like a logical approach. If I try to do it all in one if statement it will end up massive as there are quite a few permutations!

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: remove `all` from `@employee.time_logs.all`. That will trigger a query and return a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you are using Rails 3.2 and in that version, when you call `all`, your query is sent to the database and you get an array of objects as an answer.

You can do it like this:

```
if params[:show_processed] == "true"
  @logs = @employee.time_logs
else
  @logs = @employee.time_logs.non_processed
end

if params[:overtime] == 'true'
  @logs = @logs.where(:overtime => true)
end

@logs = @logs.all
```

Comment: Is there a way around it?

Comment: It's a good habit to call `.all` or `.to_a` at the end. Don't pass relations to your view.

Comment: @stefan I strongly disagree with that one. Only when you need the data should you actually execute it. And rails does this automatically for you. There is no need, never, to call `all` or `to_a` (unless you are using rails 4, then you will need the `all`). There is no harm in passing a relation to a view, with the added advantage you can always refine the relation at any stage when needed.

Comment: @nathanvda views shouldn't execute or refine database queries. Passing a plain array instead of a relation forces you to respect that boundary.

Comment: While I agree they shouldn't refine database queries, explicitly calling `all` or `to_a` somewhere makes it final and limits reusability. Just iterating over a relation will make it final when it is needed. When it is never needed (e.g. views change based on what users rights are), you have executed a query in vain. This is exactly why they introduced the "lazy querying".

Comment: If you call all in controller and you use `cache` in your views and the record is red from cache you execute a query in vain too